# Need help to enable vm replication using azure bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-site-recovery

Need help to enable vm replication using azure bicep.

My Source vm in norway east.
My source region is norway east.
My target region is norway west.

Can some pls suggest how to enable vm replication from norway east to norway west using azure bicep.

Comment: hiSatish, could you please explain a bit more ? what have you tried ? what s not working ?  these kind of things

Comment: Yes thomas......

Comment: Hi thomas, I have deployed vms in norway east using azure bicep. & I also create recovery service vault in norway west using arm templates. I need to enable vm replication from norway east to norway west using azure bicep

Comment: if you dont share you code we wont be avle to help

Comment: Thomas, pls find my code in this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1414658/getting-error-replication-provider-settings-were-n

Comment: would you be able to edit your post with the code ? its for sure easier to have eveything in one place

Comment: No thomas... ...

Comment: why not ? anyway good luck :-) hope you'll manage to fix your issue.

Comment: I have fixed my issue with out taking help from stackoverflow

Comment: good to ear it is working for you now

Answer (score 0):

As per MS doc -[Backup Resource Manager VMs using Recovery Services vault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.recoveryservices/recovery-services-backup-vms/README.md) by MS resource Ryan Hill,  The [bicep](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.recoveryservices/recovery-services-backup-vms/main.bicep) uses a flag to determine if to create a new resource or not, already created resources, please use the `existing`  [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource) in your code as below-

```
resource existingSiteRecovery 'Microsoft.SiteRecovery/vaults@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: 'arkoSiteRecoveryVault'
  scope: resourceGroup('arkoResourceGroup')
}

resource existingVM 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: 'myinternetVM'
  scope: resourceGroup('arkoResourceGroup')
}
```

Modify the above code with your resource names .
output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not working

Comment: You have the VM, your site recovery vault already created under your resource group n same region right?

Comment: I need to enable vm replication from norway east to norway west though azure bicep. I have referred ms docs. But it's not helped me. 

My scenerio like this :
* I have deployed vm in norway east with target scope as resource group. ( I have maintained separate bicep file for norway east resource group). 
* I have deployed recovery service vault with target scope as resource group in norway west. ( I have maintained separate bicep file for norway west resource group). 

Some one pls guide how to enable vm replication from norway east to norway west using azure bicep.

Comment: Please share your Bicep file for the replication policy.

Comment: it's default policy